# xcodebuild does not launch iOS 7.0 simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5, xcodebuild

I am trying to run our test suite with the iOS 7 simulator but `xcodebuild` always starts the 6.1 simulator.

```
xcodebuild -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme 'Test Smoke' -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -destination="platform='iOS Simulator',OS=7.0,name='iPhone Retina (4-inch)’" clean test
```

It works if I deinstall the iOS 6.0 and 6.1 simulator but this is not an option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You’re almost there:

The `-destination` parameter is special, in that you cannot quote the part that comes after  the “=” sign.

Meaning this:

```
xcodebuild \
    -workspace Project.xcworkspace \
    -scheme 'Test Smoke' \
    -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 \
    -destination platform='iOS Simulator',OS=7.0,name='iPhone Retina (4-inch)' \
    clean test
```

will work.

Note that the commas between the options within the `-destination` parameter must immediately be followed by the next option.

Also note that — if you specified a `name` that doesn’t match anything that actually exists — this command will just hang.

Comment: It works after removing the `=` between the `destination` and `platform`.